# Правильность расстановке знаков пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Правильно ли расставлены знаки пунктуации в предложении: "*Когда программирование - дело жизни, нет нерешаемых задач*"? Не нужно ли тире между словами "жизни" и "нет"?

Answer (score 2):

Два тире с разным значением ставить нежелательно, но  предложение можно отредактировать, чтобы  обозначить необходимые паузы и улучшить его интонационную структуру.

**Когда программИрование ― это дело жизни, то нет нерешаемых задач.**